# Some problems related to url, Javascript and Json

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, input, event-listener

I would need a little hand as I cannot get this code to work ... via the input tag in html, I should take the url entered by the user, save it in the variable pageURL, transform everything to JSON and send to my nodejs server the whole. However, when I try to do this the request is not even sent and I don't know why. If instead I try to put a simple string instead of the url in the input box, everything works perfectly ... any ideas? Thank you!!

HTML

```
<main>
        <div id="main-scanner">
            <div id="inner-scanner">
                <h1 id="scanner-h1">Ready to scan your page!</h1>
                <form id="scanner-form">
                    <label id="scanner-label">Please, enter the URL you want to scan:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="url" id="scanner-input" placeholder="              Scan me!" required>
                    <br>
                    <button id="scanner-button">Scan</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="result">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </main>
```

app.post from the server, just a test to see if it receives the request

```
app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("test")
    let requestData = req.body;
    console.log(requestData)
```

JavaScript code

```
document.getElementById("scanner-button").addEventListener("click", send);

function send(){
    var pageURL =document.getElementById('scanner-input').value;
    console.log(pageURL)
    let infos = {
        url : pageURL,
        vulnerable : false,
        report : ""
    };

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/send", true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(infos)
    let data = JSON.stringify(infos);
    request.send(data)
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `send`?

Comment: @DaveNewton I've just seen that I forgot to put the eventListener that triggers the function... I've edited the code. Just forgot to put it here

Comment: Can you provide an example of url/string that works and that doesn't work ? Do yo also see any errors in browser developer console ?

Comment: @Telman I don't see any error in the console, I know it's strange, but it simply doesn't call the function for app.post. Example... if I try to put a string like "test1234", the Node server receives correctly the JSON file, everything works; if I try something like "https://www.youtube.com" or any url it stops working and I don't know why

Comment: So yo probably see in the browser Network that javascript does a request, but Node just doesn't see that request, right ? 
If so, there could be some issue on the receiving side. Can you try to `escape` the url before sending it, like this - `url : escape(pageURL)`

Comment: @Telman I've just tried, nothing changes... in the Network section my post request says "NS_BINDING_ABORTED"

Answer (score 0):

Client:

```js
document.querySelector("#scanner-button").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const pageUrl = document.querySelector("#scanner-input").value;
  console.log(pageUrl);

  // Dont use localhost in production, host the server with a domain or public static IP address
  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/send", {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify({
      url: pageUrl,
      vunerable: false,
      report: ""
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="main-scanner">
      <div id="inner-scanner">
        <h1 id="scanner-h1">Scan Page</h1>
        <form id="scanner-form">
          <label id="scanner-label">URL To scan</label>
          <br>
          <input type="url" id="scanner-input" placeholder="URL to scan" required>
          <br>
          <button id="scanner-button">Scan</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Server:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
}));

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

You need to add the express bodyParser middleware to parse the body of POST requests. Use the new async promise based fetch API instead of the old XMLHttpRequest API.